# AttributeError: module 'sklearn.metrics' has no attribute 'calinski_harabaz_score'

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to apply this code from sklearn documentation.

I got an error: AttributeError: module 'sklearn.metrics' has no attribute 'calinski_harabaz_score'

This is the version I have:

Python version 3.5.2 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Jul 26 2016, 01:37:38)

[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.54)]

The code I used is:

```
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances
from sklearn import datasets
dataset = datasets.load_iris()
X = dataset.data
y = dataset.target

import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
kmeans_model = KMeans(n_clusters=3, random_state=1).fit(X)
labels = kmeans_model.labels_
metrics.calinski_harabaz_score(X, labels)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Upgrade scikit-learn, this function was only added recently.

Comment: When I upgrade scikit-learn in conda, I solved the same issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Pls just use

```py
metrics.calinski_harabasz_score(X, labels)
```

then,done.

Answer (score 0):

You just miss a "s" in the part: "metrics.calinski_harabaz_score(X, labels)"

instead harabaz, you should write harabasz.