# module 'sklearn' has no attribute 'cross_validation'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I am trying to split my dataset into training and testing dataset, but I am getting this error:

```
X_train,X_test,Y_train,Y_test = sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split(X,df1['ENTRIESn_hourly'])
```

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-53-5445dab94861> in <module>()
----> 1 X_train,X_test,Y_train,Y_test = sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split(X,df1['ENTRIESn_hourly'])

AttributeError: module 'sklearn' has no attribute 'cross_validation'
```

How can I handle this?

Comment: How are you importing `sklearn`?
Did you try the [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16743889/cant-use-scikit-learn-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute) [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40496969/attributeerror-module-sklearn-metrics-has-no-attribute-calinski-harabaz-scor) found online?

Comment: This is so annoying that we can't just use `import sklearn as sk` and simply start using any submodules from `sk.metrics.etc` and we have to manually add hundreds of import statements cluttering the code base and making it extremely difficult to follow any logic in the code. I hope people at `sklearn` take notice and fix this at some point.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

`sklearn` does not automatically import its subpackages. If you only imported via: `import sklearn`, then it won't work. Import with `import sklearn.cross_validation` instead.

Further, `sklearn.cross_validation` will be deprecated in version 0.20. Use `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split` instead.

Comment: Beat me to the punch. Welcome to Stack Overflow! This answer would be even better with some [linked sources](http://scikit-learn.org/0.19/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split.html) :)

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.33, random_state=101)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try this

```
X_train,X_test,Y_train,Y_test = 
    sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(X,boston_df.price)
```

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent to cross_validation in sklearn is:

```
  sklearn.model_selection
```

Answer (score 2):

"cross_validation" name is now deprecated and was replaced by "model_selection" inside the new anaconda versions. So you can use

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! Successful with this in Colab:

```
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```